# Nonhomogeneous Diffusion Fourier Expansion

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm looking for some help with the following problem.

Suppose $u$ solves $u_{t} - u_{xx} = F(x)$ on the interval $(0,\pi)$ with homogeneous Neumann conditions $u_{x} = 0$ for $x=\{0,\pi\}$ and with $F(x)$ independent of $t$.  I need to find which choices of $F$ give the solution a limit as $t\to\infty$.

I know that for diffusion with homogeneous Neumann conditions, $u(x,t)$ has the Fourier cosine expansion:
$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}A_{0} + \sum_{n=1}A_{n}e^{-n^{2}/t}\cos (nx)$
with
$A_{n} = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}u(x,0)\cos(nx)dx$.

I'm assuming that there is a similar expansion for $F(x)$ such that
$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}c_{n}\cos(nx)$.

Let $\dot{u_{n}} = \partial_{t}(A_{n}e^{-n^{2}/t}\cos (nx))$.

I then formulate a representation for each $c_n$ in terms of:
$\dot{u_{n}} + nu_{n} = c_{n}$ since $-u_{xx} = nu$ by the separation of variables procedure (where $n$ is the eigenvalue).

Solving the ODE $\dot{u_{n}} + nu_{n} = c_{n}$, I get:
$c_{n} = nu_{n} - Ce^{-nt}$ ($C$ is a constant) which doesn't make any sense to me because $c_n$ should be independent of $t$.  I'm sure that I'm taking a wrong turn someplace and would appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Informal, physics-based approach: the Neumann condition means insulation on both ends. We can't have a limit as $t\to\infty$ unless the total amount supplied by $F$ is zero, i.e, $\int_0^\pi F(x)\,dx =0$. This condition should be also sufficient, because it allows for  *stationary* solutions: $u(x,t)=u(x)$ where $u''=F$, $u'(0)=0=u'(\pi)$. (These conditions determine $u$ up to additive constant). As soon as we have a stationary solution, others ought to converge to it because the heat operator is   great at smoothing out the differences.

More precisely. First, the $n$th eigenvalue is $n^2$, not $n$. The ODE for $u_n$ is $\dot{u}_n+n^2 u_n =c_n$. When $n=0$, the solution of this ODE will not have a limit unless $c_0=0$. So we must assume $c_0=0$ (this is the condition $\int F=0$). Then $u_0 $ is constant in time. For $n>0$, a  particular solution of the ODE is $u_n=n^{-2}c_n$. General solution of homogeneous ODE is $Ce^{-n^2 t}$. So, $u_n = n^{-2}c_n+Ce^{-n^2 t} \to n^{-2}c_n$ as $t\to\infty$. This means that the solution forgets what the initial condition was (except for its average value) and converges to $$\frac12 A_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2} c_n \cos \pi n x$$